# Dependency's break the app

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I have a fairly small angular JS app, it works great but I would like to add some dependency's for instance bootstrap.ui. That's the start of my module, this works great!

```
angular.module('awesomefeed')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
```

But when I add the dependency the views stop working and the controller is never called (checked with debugger).

```
angular.module('awesomefeed',['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
```

Even with an empty dependency the problem persists.

```
angular.module('awesomefeed',[])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
```

I found a few tutorials and they all suggest that this should work, I am using strict mode I don't know if that can influence this.

EDIT: I fixed the problem, as George Stocker pointed out the repo will change over time so I'm going to describe my fix here with the code that is applicable for future reference.

I call angular.module in two places, first of all in the app.js and also in the controllers/main.js file. The calls look like this:

```
//file:app.js
angular.module('awesomefeed', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngRoute'
]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
```

and

```
//file:controllers/main.js
angular.module('awesomefeed')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
```

I wanted to add another dependency so I added ['ui.bootstrap'] to the module call in /controller/main.js, what I didn't realize was the difference between creation and retrieval of a module. ([AngularJS docs creation and retrieval of a module](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#creation-versus-retrieval)). Main.js retrieves the already created angular.module('awesomefeed'), but when I added the the dependency list to the call it stopped being a call for the already existing angular.module('awesomefeed') but instead became a creation call that would override the angular.module('awesomefeed') with the newly created almost empty angular.module('awesomefeed',['ui.bootstrap']).

The solution was to add the dependency to the list of dependency's of the creation call in app.js.

Comment: Did you run your code in a browser and look for errors in the console?

Comment: @Elian we need all the code that reproduces the issue in the question itself. When your source repo changes, this question will become useless because it won't show a future visitor what the problem is.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Phil Sandlers answer solved my problem, I will update the question to include the problem code when I have the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your code is up to date in that link, it looks like you are referencing both *scripts/app.js* and *scripts/controllers/main.js*.

These both appear to add the module "awesomefeed".  I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: This solved my problem, thank you! I added an extended explanation to my original answer.